# Wmic: whose temperatures are these?

Tags: wmic

Whose temps are these?  CPU, Mobo, HD?

```
rem Admin <cmd>
rem Results are in kelvin * 10
rem °Celsius = (result / 10 ) - 273.15

wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature
```

Results:

```
3010
3030
```

Converting:

```
(3010 / 10) - 273.15 = 27.85
(3030 / 10) - 273.15 = 29.85
```

Comment: these are current temperatures of all the child objects contained inside the logical thermal zone as implemented by the manufacturer. Query the property InstanceName along with CurrentTemperature to see which temp is for which component. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/acpi-defined-devices

Comment: So each motherboard may be different.  Dang!  Is there an wmic command to query what you recommended?

Comment: wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature,InstanceName